# docker logs: bash output redirection not working in case of 'exit 1'

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have an issue with exiting from bash in case of error (`exit 1`).

The output of my bash script is redirected to a logfile but in case of an error, the log file is not created. In the normal scenario, I have a proper log file.

What complicates my issue is that my script is executed from `Dockerfile`.

**the relevant part of my Dockerfile:**

```
RUN $ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.sh param1 param2 >$ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.sh.log 2>&1
```

**content of the bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

ORACLE_HOME=$1
DOMAIN_NAME=$2
DOMAIN_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME

echo "Oracle home: "$ORACLE_HOME
echo "Domain home: "$DOMAIN_HOME
echo "Domain name: "$DOMAIN_NAME

# validation
PROPERTIES_FILE=$ORACLE_HOME/properties/domain.properties
if [ ! -e "$PROPERTIES_FILE" ]; then
   echo "A properties file with the username and password needs to be supplied."
   exit 1
fi

...

wlst.sh ... >$ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.py.log 2>&1
RETURN_VALUE=$?
if [ $RETURN_VALUE -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Domain creation failed. Return code: $RETURN_VALUE. For more details please check the '$SCRIPT_FILE.py.log' file."
   exit 1
fi

...
```

So in case of any error, my bash script returns with `exit 1` and in this case the output redirections to logfiles do not work. In case of any error, I do not have log files that are so bad.

This is the output redirection I use:

`something.sh >something.sh.log 2>&1`

Comment: You are truncating the file on the `wlst.sh` line.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see it.

Comment: In `wlst.sh ... >$ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.py.log 2>&1` the outputfile is created or truncated. Perhaps this is another outputfile (with `py`, not `sh`), but this is what @jordanm thought.

Comment: Indeed, I have two different logfiles: $SCRIPT_FILE.sh.log and $SCRIPT_FILE.py.log. In both cases I use x.sh >x.log 2>&1 but it does not work in case of error.

Comment: The RUN command is executed during the build of the docker image. When you mount another ORACLE_HOME when you start your docker, the output is lost.

Comment: If the script exits with a status of 1, then the `RUN` command fails, and Docker won’t create an image from that step; the container filesystem is lost.  Where are you hoping the log file will exist?

Comment: @DavidMaze This is the situation exactly I have. You are correct, the final image is not created and docker just rolled back the filesystem and my logfiles. So when I start this broken image with `tail -f /dev/null` command to keep the container up and I log in, this is the reason why I can not see the logfiles which contain the error reason. So what is the proper way to handle this situation? Is there any way to redirect the outputs of all commands (outer and inned) to the standard docker output? This can be a perfect solution for me. But maybe I need to post a new for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the community finally I was able to solve my issue.

According to @DavidMaze comment, my issue was related to the behavior of the RUN command:

> If the script exits with a status of 1, then the RUN command fails, and Docker won’t create an image from that step; the container filesystem is lost.

That was the reason why I could not see any log files in the container in case of an error in the bash script.

**The solution is**

1. create a logfile in the image
2. piped it into PID 1 in order to see log content in `docker logs`
3. bash scripts need to write logs into this logfile

So everything you write to the log file will be shown in docker standard output.

**My final Dockerfile:**

```
# set the home directory
WORKDIR ${ORACLE_HOME}

# piped logfile into PID 1 in order to see log content in docker logs
RUN touch $ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.log
RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 $ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.log

# execute a script
RUN $ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.sh $ORACLE_HOME $DOMAIN_NAME $SCRIPT_FILE >$ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.log 2>&1
```

**bash script ($SCRIPT_FILE.sh):**

```
#!/bin/bash

# define variables
ORACLE_HOME=$1
DOMAIN_NAME=$2
SCRIPT_FILE=$3
DOMAIN_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME
echo "Oracle home: "$ORACLE_HOME
echo "Domain home: "$DOMAIN_HOME
echo "Domain name: "$DOMAIN_NAME
echo "Script file: "$SCRIPT_FILE

# validation
PROPERTIES_FILE=$ORACLE_HOME/properties/domain.properties
if [ ! -e "$PROPERTIES_FILE" ]; then
   echo "A properties file with the username and password needs to be supplied."
   exit 1
fi

...

wlst.sh ... $ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.py >$ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.log 2>&1
RETURN_VALUE=$?
if [ $RETURN_VALUE -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Domain creation failed. Return code: $RETURN_VALUE."
    exit 1
fi
```

**The output during the image build process looks perfect:**

```
Step 11/11 : RUN $ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.sh $ORACLE_HOME $DOMAIN_NAME $SCRIPT_FILE >$ORACLE_HOME/$SCRIPT_FILE.log 2>&1
 ---> Running in 1e7d0d80821e
Oracle home: /u01/oracle
Domain home: /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/DEV_DOMAIN
Domain name: DEV_DOMAIN
Script file: create-admin-server
Username   : weblogic
Password   : weblogic12
Creating password file for Administration server...
Creating WebLogic domain...

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

domain name               : DEV_DOMAIN
domain path               : /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/DEV_DOMAIN
admin server name         : AdminServer
admin server port         : 7001
machine name              : host_1
cluster name              : DEV_DOMAIN_CLUSTER
managed server name prefix: managed_server
managed server port       : 7011
production mode enabled   : true


WebLogic domain has been created successfully
Script completed successfully.
Removing intermediate container 1e7d0d80821e
Successfully built b4f63eb00e62
Successfully tagged <my-image name>:<version>

 ---> b4f63eb00e62
```